# Error While Converting JavaScript to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert some js to ts and got error in **canSave method** .My JavaScript code is,

```js
            scope.canSave = function () {
                if (scope.category.orderNumber != scope.list) {
                    !_this.orderNumberAlreadyExist(scope.list, scope.category);
                }
            };
```

and when I'm trying to convert that into TypeScript . I was getting `Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '() => boolean'` and `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'Category[]'` in command prompt. What was my mistake and what can i do now, can  some one clarify me.

Comment: [`processResource`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/jvm/tasks/ProcessResources.html) "Copies resources from their source to their target directory, potentially processing them." How should this command convert JavaScript to TypeScript?

Comment: I will process two commands to convert js to ts,they are the above one and ( gradlew devResource) . These are the steps am following for the Conversion. I was getting that above error in the 1st command itself !!

Comment: for helping you we need to know how are category and list declared (in typescript). Please post your complete code and also the lines where you are getting the errors

Comment: @iberbeu , Now i edited my code, You can check

Comment: But you haven't defined anything using typescript yet. If you compile the code with tsc it will compile since all js code is compiled. You cannot get an error

Comment: My javaScript code is working fine, no issues there. The Problem occurs while am trying to convert that into TypeScript . That's why am struggling this much of time !

Comment: then convert it manually. You will learn and you won't have any problems with external libraries. It is no that difficult. When you have converted something come back with your doubts and we'll help you

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you have an automatic tool for converting javascript to typescript? How does it know about the type `Category`? And why are you converting the js to ts to begin with? (as you wrote in the comment to an answer that: "i don't want to change my JavaScript code", so what's the point in having the ts code?)

Comment: @iberbeu, Finally i converted javaScript to TypeScript  manually. And find the solution for that also . Thanks For your idea . Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you're running into the fact that TypeScript (as the name would suggest!) has a much stricter type system than JavaScript, so a lot of things that would be allowed in the latter will cause the TypeScript compiler to shout at you.

You have two issues here:

- Somewhere in your code, `scope.canSave` is being defined to be a function with no parameters that returns a boolean. TypeScript represents this as `() => boolean` - if it took a number as a parameter, it'd look something like `(number) => boolean`, and so on. Your new function definition, on the other hand, doesn't return anything at all. TypeScript represents this type of function as `() => void` - it can tell this doesn't match up to what `scope.canSave` *should* be, so it gives you an error message.
- `scope.category.orderNumber` is defined as being a number, but `scope.list` is defined as being an array of `Category` objects. Those two types aren't comparable (you can't convert an array of objects into a number), so TypeScript gives you an error when you try to use the `!=` operator on them.

So effective, TypeScript is doing exactly what it's designed to do here - it caught two issues with your code that might have gone unnoticed in plain JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks joe , You are telling me the reason for my error but i need solution buddy.  And i don't want to change my JavaScript code, Because that logic which i was used in my code is important for my Application. so i need to convert that into TypeScript .

Comment: @Becky: For me to be able to give a definite solution, you'll need to add the part of the code where you initially defined the variables/types (in other words, where you initially set up your `scope`) to your question; that's where the fixes are going to have to take place.